# Probably unneeded returns

Tags: haskell, monads

This is my first "useful" Haskell program. It's invoked with filenames as arguments where the last filename is the destination to which the content of all other files will be concatenated. As far as I can tell it's working but I don't like the two returns in the main function and would like to know how I can get rid of the do in the concatFiles function.

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.IO (hClose, hPutStr, openFile, IOMode(WriteMode))


concatFiles :: FilePath -> [FilePath] -> IO ()
concatFiles destination files = do
    writeHandle <- openFile destination WriteMode
    mapM (writeToDestination writeHandle) files
    hClose writeHandle
    where
        writeToDestination writeHandle file =
            hPutStr writeHandle =<< readFile file

main = do
    args <- getArgs
    argc <- return $ length args
    destination <- return $ last args
    concatFiles destination $ take (argc-1) args
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your `argc <- return $ length args` , the reason the compiler is telling you to use the return is because in `do` notation, monadic binding lines must be the form:

```
binding <- value wrapped in whatever monad you're using
```

So `length args` just returns an `Int`, but Haskell wants an `IO Int`. By doing `return $ length args`, you lift the value returned by `length args` into the `IO` monad.

You are correct in smelling something funny here. Haskell provides a much cleaner way of assigning non-monadic values to be used inside of `do` notation with the `let` keyword.

You can replace those two lines with:

```
let argc = length args
    destination = last args
```

Note that bindings must have the same indentation level within a `let` assignment block.

But really, there is more to improve! In Haskell, the four most common list partitions are:

1. First element (`head`)
2. Last element (`last`)
3. Everything but the first (`tail`)
4. Everything but the last (`init`)

So with `init` we can eliminate the need for argc, changing your `main` to

```
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let destination = last args
    concatFiles destination $ init args
```

But really, the word `destination` is longer than the function call `last args`, and doesn't really add much clarity, so we can change that, too, removing the need for the `let` entirely!

```
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    concatFiles (last args) (init args)
```

And if you *really* wanted to become more intimately familiar with how `do` notations and monads in general work, we can actually remove the `do` notation and replace it with a `>>=` operator by doing

```
main = getArgs >>= \args -> concatFiles (last args) (init args)
```

So as a quick recap of what is happening here, we are calling `getArgs`, which returns a list of arguments wrapped in the `IO` monad. The `>>=` (bind) operator takes that `IO` value, extracts the value inside, and sends it into the function on the right side of the `>>=` operator, where it gets bound to the argument `args`.

Comment: If you're going to get fancy by using `>>=`, you may as well get rid of the lambda as well! `main = getArgs >>= concatFiles <$> last <*> init`.

Comment: @amalloy exactly what I was thinking